# Creating a different width navbar in different parts?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about creating a navbar something like this which is having different sections with different curves and and angles? ( I was thinking of using different spans and adjust them using Transform property. Am I way too off or there is some other easier method? Also a method such that it wont look ridiculous in a mobile view.) :

[image]

Comment: mb linear-gradient

Comment: How are you going to achieve the effect above using Linear Gradient?

Comment: Maybe SVGs will help you

Comment: background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, blue 50%, white 50%);

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be multiple background images. One wide image for the blue background and blue line, and one for the white line. Make them both pretty wide so that you are sure it will work on multiple resolutions. Align the blue background to the left and the white line to the right.

([Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su3Tu.jpg))

The CSS would be a bit of a mess, with all the diagonal lines. Hard to maintain and not exactly browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this might help

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="logo float-left"></div>
    <div class="center-nav float-left">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="social-media-icons float-left"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.logo{
   background: url('img/image.jpg');
   width: 20%; /*example */
   height: 242px;
 }
 .float-left{
    float:left;
 }
 .center-nav{
      /* crop image of width 1px height 242px (image height) */
     background: url(cropped.png);
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
     width:80%; /*example */
 }
 .social-media-icons{
      /* Same as .center-nav (crop the background of social media icons and repeat-x) */
 }
```

In this way you can also achieve cross browser compatibility